# How to calculate exposure of beta and alpha decay

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation

Is there a way to calculate exposure in roentgen from activity of from q-values? I currently have the activity of a beta decay in mCi over a certain amount of time and the total amount of energy, which I calculated from the q-value for a single beta decay multiplied by the total number of decays. Is it possible to calculate the exposure from this?

Comment: The Particle Data Group maintains a recipe that's good for back-of-the-envelope calculations: http://pdg.lbl.gov/2015/reviews/rpp2015-rev-radioactivity.pdf